# Using Firebase with Expo: how to properly setup and test Firebase config?

Tags: firebase, expo

I am trying to do a very simple expo react native project that can save to firebase.

Following the guide here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase.html

Step 1: How to set these values correctly? Where to find them?

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
  authDomain: "<YOUR-AUTH-DOMAIN>",
  databaseURL: "<YOUR-DATABASE-URL>",
  storageBucket: "<YOUR-STORAGE-BUCKET>"
};
```

I had a difficult time figuring out the exact details for step 1, so I thought I share some guidelines, and a code to test step 2 easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will tell you, where to find each value using the number next to their field, and then provide a code to test it.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    projectId: "", // 0
    apiKey: "", // 1
    authDomain: "", // 2
    databaseURL: "", // 3
    storageBucket: "", // 4
    messagingSenderId: "", // 5
};
```

All of the following steps start from the project main page (which can be reach by opening your project [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/)). 
0, 1: 
**projectId** and **apiKey** can be both found by clicking on the **Gear icon** next to the Overview tab, **then Project settings**. In the **General tab**, you will see Project ID, and Web Api Key.

2: 
**authDomain** is `<projectId>`.firebaseapp.com.

3: 
**databaseURL** can be found by clicking on Database tab. It should be: https://`<projectId>`.firebaseio.com/.

4: 
**storageBucket** can be found by clicking on Storage tab. It should be: gs://`<projectId>`.appspot.com/.

5: 
**messagingSenderId** can be found by clicking on the **Gear icon** next to the Overview tab, **then Project settings**. In the **Cloud Messaging tab**, you will see Sender ID.

---

After these are all set properly, you can test it with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    // ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => updateDB(1, 10, 20)}
          title="Update DB on Firebase"
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}

function updateDB(userID, fieldValue1, fieldValue2) {
  firebase.database().ref(userID).set({
    field1: fieldValue1,
    field2: fieldValue2,
  });
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```